# Same function for updating and Saving?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

My code to use the function for updating is here and it works also

```
[HttpPost]

public bool SaveDefCompny(DefCompanyDTO DefCmpny)
{

    using (RPDBEntities db = new RPDBEntities())
    {
        using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
        {
            //the problem is here incase of saving 

                var UpdateDefCmpnyId = (from CmpnyId in db.DefCompanies
                                        where CmpnyId.Id == DefCmpny.Id
                                        select CmpnyId).First();

                List<DefCompany> list = new List<DefCompany>();
                list.Add(UpdateDefCmpnyId);
                try
                {
                    foreach (DefCompany DefCmpny1 in list)
                    {
                        DefCmpny1.Id = DefCmpny1.Id;

                        DefCmpny1.ShortName = DefCmpny.ShortName;
                        DefCmpny1.FullName = DefCmpny.FullName;
                        DefCmpny1.ContactPerson = DefCmpny.ContactPerson;
                        DefCmpny1.Address1 = DefCmpny.Address1;


                        DefCmpny1.CompanyCity = DefCmpny.CompanyCity;
                        DefCmpny1.CompanyState = DefCmpny.CompanyState;
                        DefCmpny1.CompanyCountry = DefCmpny.CompanyCountry;
                        DefCmpny1.ZipPostCode = DefCmpny.ZipPostCode;
                        DefCmpny1.TelArea = DefCmpny.TelArea;
                        DefCmpny1.CurrentCurrencyCode = DefCmpny.CurrentCurrencyCode;


                        db.SaveChanges();
                        trans.Complete();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {


                }

            }
            return false;
        }

}
```

when I try to save instead of updating the line of code

```
var UpdateDefCmpnyId = (from CmpnyId in db.DefCompanies
                                            where CmpnyId.Id == DefCmpny.Id
                                            select CmpnyId).First();
```

gives null value and hence saving fails because record is new and not present in database so how to handle null in case of saving how to use try catch so that when value is null it proceed to saving code that add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something along these lines:

```
var UpdateDefCmpnyId = (from CmpnyId in db.DefCompanies
                                    where CmpnyId.Id == DefCmpny.Id
                                    select CmpnyId).FirstOrDefault();
if(UpdateDefCmpnyId == null)
{
    //insert
    //(handle the id however you need to for insert. depending on your setup, you might be able to leave it empty and let the database put it in for you)
}
else
{
    //update
    //set the id as you do in the question
}
```

Comment: but it stop when linq query returns null does not proceed to if else

Comment: Did you notice that I changed `.First()` to `.FirstOrDefault()`?